# Registrar extensión con NSIS

Tags: archivo

Estoy intentanto registrar un tipo de extension a mi programa desde NSIS y a la vez mostrar un item en el menu contextual para enviar dicho tipo de archivo al programa. Entontré un script que al parecer no es oficial de NSIS porque tuve que instalarlo por mi cuenta, se llama [File Association](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/File_Association). Funciona bien, me muestra el item en el menu contextual, pero con algo extra, le antecede la palabra **Edit**. Dejo la parte del archivo .nsis donde configuro lo antes dicho.

```
Section "Register extension"
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  ${registerExtension} "$INSTDIR\jkvmachine.exe" ".jkv" "Procesar archivo"
SectionEnd
```

Entonces en el menu contextual me aparece **Edit Procesar archivo**, ¿Será que debo configurar algo? Anteriormente utilicé lo siguiente:

```
Section "Register extension"
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  WriteRegStr HKCR ".jkv" "" "WI.jkv"
  WriteRegStr HKCR "WI.jkv" "" "JKV file"
  WriteRegStr HKCR "WI.jkv\shell" "" "Install"
  WriteRegStr HKCR "WI.jkv\shell\Install\command" "" '"$INSTDIR\jkvmachine.exe" "%1"'
  WriteRegStr HKCR "WI.jkv\DefaultIcon" "" "$INSTDIR\jkvmachine.exe"
SectionEnd
```

Pero es mas largo y la desventaja frente al otro es que no tiene algo directo para quitar l asociacion de la extension, el otro me permite hacer lo siguiente:

```
${unregisterExtension} ".jkv" "Procesar archivo"
```

Y ya con eso se desinstala todo lo correspondiente, tambien quisiera añadir un icono al item en el menu pero eso ya es algo extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagino que ya habrás dado con la respuesta ya que ha pasado mucho tiempo...
La solución es si.plemente en la llave del registro command, meter el string que quieras en el default. Si lo haces desde un archivo sería:

```
HKLM "....WI.jkv\shell\command"
@="Procesar archivo"
"Icon"="C:\\Carpeta\\iconopreferido.ico"
```

No estoy seguro, pero prueba de quitar ese install y mete la llave command en shell. Y ojo con las barras"\" , cuando lo quieres importar desde un archivo .reg siempre se doblan